# C# Setting File Value

Tags: c#, version, setting

Currently I'm using setting file for my application. Problem is despite one of the values changed by itself everytime. Is this about setting file mechanics or what ?
(I'm using it for version controlling and updating)

Comment: Add more description. What is the name of the value changing? What is it changing to? When does it change? We have no way to answer this, besides if it's a Version attribute, of which if it's defined as: [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")] VS will know to auto increment every build.

Comment: My application is Updater application for my main application. In setting file there is integer value called Ver. When launcher started It connecting to the server and check last version and compares it with setting file value, if required It download files and updates files and changes Ver value from setting file.
Problem is that; despite of there is no line that alters Ver value in anyway, It changed by itself. It seems like doesn't use Setting File that in Startup Folder. This is my problem